# bluetooth communicator

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I want to fetch information from probe (hand held device for measuring temperature) having Bluetooth and display the information on an android device. Please suggest the simplest approach for doing this and how I am supposed to fetch the information.

Comment: You are providing little information. Important details are for instance whether or not the probe supports bluetooth serial port connection. If it does not, what other bluetooth profiles does it implement?

Answer (score 1):

1. Find documentation of this device.
2. Find in documentation UUID is uses to deliver results.
3. pair device with phone
4. On Phone side find a paired device which handless specified UUID ([getBondedDevices()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#getBondedDevices%28%29), [getUuids()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#getUuids%28%29))
5. On Phone side when you find the phone open socket with that UUID ([createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord%28java.util.UUID%29)).
6. Back to device documentation and check how you query for result, what is format of delivered data, than do respective parsing and processing of that data ([getInputStream()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html#getInputStream%28%29), [getOutputStream()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothSocket.html#getOutputStream%28%29)).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

With the amount of information you are giving out pretty much all that can be said is consult the [Android Bluetooth documentation for developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html) and the [respective API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/package-summary.html), which you should of course have already done.